# Outlook Web Addin - get SMTP details

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Is there a way to get the SMTP details of the current mail from an Outlook web addin? I see that the VSTO addin has this.

Comment: You should provide mode info on what kind of SMTP details are you looking for? Just SMTP e-mail address or something else? What does this mean "current mail"? Are you talking about recipients or sender? Point on VSTO functionality you have discovered and would like to get with Office.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got all the mime data through this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> 
      <soap:Header> 
        <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" /> 
      </soap:Header> 
      <soap:Body> 
        <GetItem 
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
                    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> 
          <ItemShape> 
            <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape> 
            <t:IncludeMimeContent>true</t:IncludeMimeContent>
          </ItemShape> 
          <ItemIds> 
            <t:ItemId Id="  item_id  "/> 
          </ItemIds> 
        </GetItem> 
      </soap:Body> 
    </soap:Envelope>
```

The mime data can then be decoded to get more details about the message